# lex generates no output

Tags: macos, lex

Just following the tutorial at https://begriffs.com/posts/2021-11-28-practical-parsing.html. My .l file looks like:

```
/* catcot.l */

%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%

cot { printf("portable bed"); }
cat { printf("thankless pet"); }
cats { printf("anti-herd"); }
```

I give the command:

```
lex catcot.l
```

And the generated output is empty:

```
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 falk  staff  141 Dec 27 14:19 catcot.l
-rw-r--r--  1 falk  staff    0 Dec 27 14:19 lex.yy.c
```

Running with -v shows that lex is really running (`flex version 2.5.35 Apple(flex-32)`) and introducing errors in the code gives the expected error messages, but no output ever gets generated.

Comment: That sounds like a broken installation. A common problem is a bad install of `m4`, which flex uses to process the skeleton. Can you check if `m4` is actually runnable on your system?

Comment: Well, `m4 --help` generates the expected output.

Comment: Ok, I guess the next step would be `dtrace` or whatever macos uses for that these days. I'm pretty sure that the output file is created just before `m4` is invoked with stdout pointing at the output file. That's the end of the code generation. So an empty output file usually means that `m4` blew up, which certainly shouldn't happen in a correct installation. Flex uses `$PATH` to find `m4`, so it's pretty simple to interpose your own `m4`, even a shell script. A starting point might be modifying PATH to start with a temp directory in which m4 is aliased to a script which logs the arguments.

Comment: I've done that sort of thing before to track down installation issues.

Comment: @rici, looks like you're right; I tried the same thing on a different computer and it worked. I suppose now it's just a matter of uninstalling and reinstalling lex and/or m4.

Comment: If you're going to reinstall flex, I'd suggest using a newer one than the antique you seem to have been given. I don't think that's the problem, but it surely can't hurt. (Also bison.)

Comment: I worry that the version I'm using was bundled with XCode, so uninstalling it might not be trivial.

Comment: Flex has very few dependencies, and practically nothing depends on it (since it's common to provide pregenerated scanners and parsers as part of the source distribution). But I haven't used XCode for more than a decade, so I can't claim to have a direct line to the truth. :-) (FWIW, my linux box has six different flex versions simultaneously installed, and I haven't encountered any problems with that. I keep them all around in case someone asks a version-dependent flex question. They're all built from source, with essentially the only customization being a different `--prefix` for each one.)